# python list within list initialization and printing

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am trying to append an element to a list within a list that has an incremented value each time:

```
def get_data(file):
  matrix = [ ['one','two','three'] ] #list of lists
  test_count = 0
  line_count = 0 #keep track of which line we are on

  for line in file:
    if line.find('example') != -1: #test for example string
      temp_a = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",line)[0]
      print matrix[test_count][0] #should print 'one'
      matrix[test_count][0].insert(temp_a) #should insert temp_a instead of 'one'
      test_count += 1 #go to next "new" list in the matrix
      line_count += 1 #go to next line
```

What I want is the result of findall to go into temp_a and from there to insert it into index 0 of the first list within a list. Then the next time findall is true, I want to insert temp_a to index 0 of the second list.

For example if the first temp_a value is 9,  I would like the first list in the matrix to be:
[ [9,y,z] ]
If on the second findall my temp_a is 4, I want the matrix to become:
[ [9,y,z], [4,y,z] ]

The above code is my best attempt so far.
I have 2 questions:

1) How can I initialize a 'list of lists' if the amount of lists isn't fixed?

2) The list ['one','two','three'] was to test with printing what is going on. If I try to print out matrix[test_count][0], I get an "index out of range" error, but the moment I change it to print out matrix[0][0] it prints 'one' correctly. Is there something with the scope that I'm missing here?

Comment: It would help if you post a sample input file, and expected output.

Comment: Lists don't have any contents unless you put something in them. So, accessing `matrix[0]` might fail if there is nothing there. However, `matrix.append(temp_a)` will definitely add something to the end of the list.

Comment: yes I know matrix.append will add to the end, but I want to add to matrix[var][0].append

the sample input file is simple line by line text, the problem isn't with file input but with the matrix definition and appending...

Comment: What exactly does this file you're reading from look like? I made a test file and the `index out of bounds` error I got was on your regex so I assume my file is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) Like this: `matrix = []`

Simply put, this just creates an empty list that you can append anything you want into, including more lists. So `matrix.append([1,2,3])` gives you a list like this: `[[1,2,3]]`

2) So you're `index out of range` error is coming from the fact that you're incrementing `test_count` to 1 but your matrix is remaining length of 1 (meaning it only has the 0 index) since you never append anything. In order to get the output that you want you're going to need to make a few changes:

```
def get_data(file):
  example_list = ['one','two','three']
  matrix = [] #list of lists
  test_count = 0
  line_count = 0 #keep track of which line we are on

  for line in file:
    if line.find('example') != -1: #test for example string
      temp_a = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",line)[0]
      new_list = example_list[:]
      new_list[0] = temp_a
      matrix.append(new_list)
      test_count += 1 #go to next "new" list in the matrix
      line_count += 1 #go to next line

print matrix #[['boxes', 'two', 'three'], ['equilateral', 'two', 'three'], ['sphere', 'two', 'three']]
```

Comment: I tried it the way you say. It errors with the same index out of range on the print line that should print 'one'

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky really...can you post a few lines from the file you're parsing so I can see exactly what you're going for?

Comment: Ah. It seems like this is really necessary :)
Example lines:

#001= squares('boxes',$,$); \n
#002= triangles('equilateral',$,$); \n
#003= circles('sphere',$,$); \n

the output matrix should be [ [boxes] [equilateral] [sphere] ]

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky So the output is list of lists that are only size 1? Why not a list of strings then? `['boxes','equilateral','sphere']`

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky Regardless, my edit should produce the output you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

For 2), did you try to print out test_count? Since your test_count+=1 is in if statement, it shouldn't be out of range without printing "one".

For 1), you could do this before insert:

```
if test_count == len(matrix):
    matrix.append([])
```

It adds a new empty list if test_count of out range of matrix.

**EDIT:**

"Out of range" caused by line `temp_a = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",line)[0]` because it can't find anything. So it's an empty list, and [0] out of range.

```
def get_data(file):
  matrix = [ ['one','two','three'] ] #list of lists
  test_count = 0
  line_count = 0 #keep track of which line we are on

  for line in file:
    if line.find('example') != -1: #test for example string
      temp_a = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",line)
      if temp_a:
        temp_a = temp_a[0]
      else:
        continue # do something if not found
      print(matrix[test_count][0]) #should print 'one'
      new_list = matrix[test_count][:]
      new_list[0] = temp_a
      matrix[test_count].append(new_list) #should insert temp_a instead of 'one'
      test_count += 1 #go to next "new" list in the matrix
      line_count += 1 #go to next line
```

Comment: I tried it but it still had and issue with the index range. I also tried just to matrix.append([]) without an if, but it still had the same error...

Comment: I just ran your code. Out of range is not from matrix, it's from temp_a = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",line)[0]. It can't find anything.

Comment: I tried it as you say. The only thing I'm doing differently is .insert instead of .append but it should be the same right? In both cases it still does the error..

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky For one the insert in your question produces an error as you're calling `insert` on a string, not a list. Secondly `insert` requires two arguments while `append` does not.

Comment: L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index